# Formula field for in-year revenue, needs a tweak

Tags: formula-field

The current formula is:

((( DATE(2023,11,30)- ( Production_Live_Date__c )+ 30.43685))/ 30.43685)* List_price_MRR__c

- Effectively calculates the in-year revenue forecast based on the go-live date in the current year.

**I need to add an if-statement to make deals which go live in 2024 = $0**, Please help :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`IF(NOT(ISBLANK(Production_Live_Date__c)) && YEAR(Production_Live_Date__c) == 2024,0,(((( DATE(2023,11,30)- ( Production_Live_Date__c )+ 30.43685))/ 30.43685)* List_price_MRR__c))`

Comment: Thanks! This worked!

Answer (score 0):

Try below:

```
IF(
  YEAR(Production_Live_Date__c) >= YEAR(TODAY()),
  0,
  (((DATE(2023, 11, 30) - Production_Live_Date__c + 30.43685)) / 30.43685) * List_price_MRR__c
)
```

Instead of using 2024 as hardcoded you can make it generic. Do the same for 2023 date based on your requirement.